# Populate one picklist value based on other picklist value/numeric value in custom object of Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have custom object trainer which has below fields

- Trainer Name - Text
- Experience - numeric
- Trainer Technology - Multi select picklist with values - dotnet, java, salesforce, tableau, C, CPP
- Trainer Education details - picklist with values - BE, ME, BSC, MSC
- Country - picklist with values - India, USA, UK
- Trainer Category - picklist with values- Silver, Gold, Platinum

How can I achieve below requirements, I want the picklist value to be set based on conditions before clicking on save, on record creation page. I am not able to do it through field dependencies. Please suggest if I need to go for customization

- We need to ensure that for dotnet, java, salesforce only BE or ME trainers are allowed
- For courses c or cpp we need only BSc or MSc trainers
- For Tableau we only India is allowed
- If trainer has more than 15 years of experience then Trainer Category should be Platinum

Answer (score 0):

You have several different kinds of objectives here.

> - We need to ensure that for dotnet, java, salesforce only BE or ME trainers are allowed
> - For courses c or cpp we need only BSc or MSc trainers
> - For Tableau we only India is allowed

These are all things you can set up with picklist dependency or Validation Rules, as you prefer.

> If trainer has more than 15 years of experience then Trainer Category should be Platinum

This can be a Validation Rule to require the user to select the right value or any kind of automation (Workflow Rule, Flow, Apex Trigger).

> I want the picklist value to be set based on conditions before clicking on save, on record creation page

You can't set the Trainer Category before save without building custom UI components.